# GLMM with numeric and categorical/binary DEPENDENT variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, binary-data, glmm, continuous-data

Is there a way to build a single model (including both fixed and random effects) with numeric and categorical/binary outcomes?
I know that I could do one linear mixed model and one generalized linear mixed model using R, but can I somehow combine these models?

Comment: Please give more context. Why do you need a combined model? What do you intend to do with it? ...

Comment: It's just a hypothetical question. I can imagine a study where I wanted to find out how my 2 dependent variables (1 binary and 1 continuous) are influenced by f.i. 5 continuous and 2 categorical independent variables.

Comment: search for joint modelling